# How to restore PATH on mac?

Tags: bash, zsh, path

I've installed iTerm2 and then zsh on my mac. Somehow my PATH is broken now and cannot node or npm commands. I'm having a struggle, I've tried uncommenting the following line in .zshrc:

#export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

but such file doesn't exist, I've also tried to look for ~/.bash_profile, but it also doesn't exist. Where should I look at to find my PATH?

Comment: [Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.) | The Lumber Room](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/)

Comment: @DavidPostill can you elaborate a little bit more on how to restore my PATH variable back to what it used to be?

Comment: You need to check the zsh startup files for path statements and correct them where necessary.